# Passing variable into MySQL using Python 2.7

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7

I've been trying to insert a string value from a variable in Python 2.7 into a MySQL statement.
I can't seem to get it to work, could someone point me in the right direction?

```
import MySQLdb

country_name = raw_input("Which country would you like?\n")

dbh = MySQLdb.connect(host="localhost",
                      user="boole",
                      passwd="****",
                      db="mySQL_Experiment_1")
sth = dbh.cursor()
sth.execute("""SELECT name, population FROM world WHERE name=(%s)""", (country_name))
for row in sth:
    print row[0], row[1]
```

It outputs:

```
/usr/bin/python2.7 "/home/boole/Documents/Python Scripts/mySQL_Experiment_1/main.py"
Which country would you like?
Canada
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/boole/Documents/Python Scripts/mySQL_Experiment_1/main.py", line 10, in <module>
    sth.execute("""SELECT name, population FROM world WHERE name=(%s)""", (country_name))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py", line 187, in execute
    query = query % tuple([db.literal(item) for item in args])
TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Thanks,
Boole

Comment: What happens when you run this?

Comment: Sorry, I knew I forgot something!

Comment: Try this cursor.execute("SELECT name, population FROM world where name = %s", [country_name])

Comment: Thanks @Prateek it worked perfectly!

Comment: @Boole You are welcome, I will write it down as an answer please do mark it as a correct solution to your problem. So that it becomes useful for others if they are facing this issue.

Comment: @Boole: Please mark it as an answer if you found it useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
cursor.execute("SELECT name, population FROM world where name = %s", [country_name])
```